# Example of CW complex not $\Delta$-complex, and $\Delta$-complex not Simplicial complex.

Tags: cw-complexes, simplicial-complex

I have been searching for an example of a topological space $X$, which admits a CW complex structure, but no $\Delta$-complex structure. Notice that $S^2$ is not a valid example for what I want. I know that $S^2$ can be constructed as a CW complex with one 0-cell and one 2-cell, and that this is not a $\Delta$-complex structure. But there is a $\Delta$-complex structure for $S^2$, with one 0-cell, one 1-cell and two 2-cells.

I have the same question  for the comparison of $\Delta$-complexes and simplicial complexes. One example that I found is $S^1$, but as in the previous case, this doesn't work. Even though the traditional construction with one 0-cell and one 1-cell is a $\Delta$-complex and not a simplicial complex, you can still construct $S^1$ as a simplicial complex with three 0-cells and three 1-cells.

So if you have any example of a space that admits one structure but not the other, or if there is some general result comparing this three structures, I would be really happy if you share this with me.

Thanks